Where do we define middlewares in nuxt.config.js in Nuxt 3?
I'm migrating a large application from Nuxt 2 to Nuxt 3 and I decided to create a fresh Nuxt 3 application and move code from my previous version to this one but I encountered a problem in my nuxt.config.js file when adding my old middleware array in the configuration. Here's what it looks like:
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  // ... some other configs
  router: {
    middleware: ["redirect", "authenticated"], 
    // line above returns an error that this option doesn't exist
    base: `${process.env.ROUTER_BASE}`,
  },

I already have my middleware folder in my project structure but I want to know how should I define this in my config file, I used to have a problem in Nuxt 2 where I needed to specify the order in which my middleware functions where executed and I fixed that by setting the order in my middleware array, I'm looking for the same behavior in Nuxt 3 but I can't find any docs on this part of my migration

https://nuxt.com/docs/migration/plugins-and-middleware#migration-1  and https://nuxt.com/docs/guide/directory-structure/middleware#ordering-global-middleware

In Nuxt 3 you can add a global route middleware by placing it into /middleware directory with a .global suffix
For example
middleware/
--| redirect.global.ts
--| authenticated.global.ts

You can read about ordering them here

There is this section in the docs about ordering middleware.
Middlewares are run alphabetically, but you can have more control by using 'alphabetical' numbering.
e.g
middleware
--| 00.redirect.global.ts
--| 01.authenticated.global.ts

